# File system with read/write logging by user

Tags: filesystems

Is there any file system - or monitoring tool - which logs which users have read and written which files?

Something like this:

```
2014-01-21 13:45:45  john  12939  /users/john/hello.txt   write
2014-01-21 13:45:55  paul  12939  /users/john/hello.txt   read
```

This should be restrictable to certain folders (only user files are interesting, not system files).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install `auditd`. It is a useful tool to setup watches for specific files/folders operations. It support different operations: `r=read, w=write, x=execute, a=attribute`.

You can add a specific watch with a specific filter key for easy search.

Here is a [simple page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html) that explains how to install and use `auditd`.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, [auditd](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/01/a-brief-introduction-to-auditd/) it's a well tested solution. Windows has builtin [tools](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/windows_server_2008_security/securing-auditing-high-risk-files-windows-servers.html) for auditing file access.

Use this tools carefully, auditing can impact on the server's performance if not used wisely.

Comment: Interesting! However I am on OS X, which seems to have a slightly non-standard implementation of auditd with sparse documentation. Anyone know how to work this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question [linux-file-access-monitoring](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12247/linux-file-access-monitoring)

It mentions two ways of achieving what you need but I think the second suits better your needs:

http://loggedfs.sourceforge.net/

It seems to have little dependency and provide the exact functionnality that you need.